# Русские подсказки в "среде разработчика" Java

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

Я плохо знаю английский, но изучать Java охота. Подскажите, существует ли возможность добавления в "среду разработки" подсказок и описаний методов на русском языке?

Comment: ОхотО? Плохо английский знаешь? Тяжело тебе, наверное.
Какая у тебя "среда разработки"? Код можно и в русифицированном блокноте писать, только компилятор иногда запускать для проверки.

Comment: >Я плохо знаю английский

Так начинайте знать его хорошо, для программиста это обязательно.

>охото

Без обид, но у вас и с русским не очень.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если поискать, то кое-что кое-где русифицировать можно, но в любом случае около 60-80% будет на английском, если учитывать только язык и IDE, а так около 90% информации есть только на английском.

**Так как большая часть информации на английском, вам всё равно нужно его осваивать.**

*Что делать, если нужно кодить уже сейчас, а английский на нуле?*
Есть 3 варианта:

1. Гуглить по коду ошибки или ключевым словам из неё - самые простые и популярные описаны на русском (крайне хреновый метод обучения).
2. Использовать переводчики (гугл, яндекс, промт) - более-менее переводят словосочетания, если они состоят из общеупотребительных слов (т. е. для технической литературы бесполезная вещь).
3. Использовать электронные словари - переводить долго, но очень хорошо усваиваются популярные слова, показывают все возможные значения слова с учётом специфики IT, можно    использовать +100500 словарей, и хоть в одном да найдётся полезная информация.

Лично я на всех устройствах использую GoldenDict и огромное количество скаченных словарей (около 15гб), мегаудобная вещь! Так, например, увидев незнакомое слово "выделить" => "комбинация клавиш" => "открывается всплывающее окно с описанием слова", пара секунд - и я узнаю новое слово.

Comment: Не понял, что такое GoldenDict ?

Comment: GoldenDict  это агрегатор словарей, устанавливаешь её, загружаешь +100500 словарей из любых областей, далее вешаешь быстрый запуск на клавиатурную комбинацию и пользуешься...